# How to remove zero width spaces from string in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

I need to filter invisible character from a string. In the attached screen shot, string "​Cilantro" has some hidden character and when i get count of this before and after removing hidden character it shows different character count.

I just want to filter invisible characters not special characters, for example I dont want to filter á, ã è etc characters.

Note: I removed hidden characters using "delete" button.

For the reference I am adding here the String with invisible character: "​Cilantro". I am not sure if it will show at your end too.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Swift 5 or later**

You can use new Character [isLetter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/character/3127011-isletter) property

```
let del = Character(UnicodeScalar(127)!)
let string = "Cilantro\(del)\(del)"
print(string.count) // "10\n"
let filtered = string.filter { $0.isLetter }
print(filtered.count)  // "8\n"
```

---

```
let string = "cafe\u{301}"
let filtered = string.filter { $0.isLetter }
print(filtered)  // "café"
```

---

If you just want to remove zero width spaces from your string you can do as follow:

---

```
extension Character {
    static let zeroWidthSpace = Self(.init(0x200B)!)
    var isZeroWidthSpace: Bool { self == .zeroWidthSpace }
}
```

---

```
extension Bool {
    var negated: Bool { !self }
}
```

---

```
let str = "​Cilantro"
print(str.count) // 9

let filtered = str.filter(\.isZeroWidthSpace.negated)
print(filtered.count) // 8
```

Comment: As of Swift 5 you can simply do `string.filter { $0.isASCII }`

Comment: It is part of https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0221-character-properties.md.

Comment: @MartinR nice there is a lot of new stuff coming up next release.

Comment: Actually there is a problem with your implementation, it relies on the “precomposed” representation of characters. Try it with `let string = "cafe\u{301}"`

Comment: @LeoDabus Thanks for answering my question, I just want to remove invisible characters. For example i do want some special characters like "è, á", and above method will not allow these characters.

Comment: Well you need to define which characters are valid

Comment: @CMA edited to filter only letters. If you want to allow digits, white spaces and newlines you just need to add it to the logic `{ $0.isLetter || $0.isNumber }`